# AWS how to achieve encryption in transport and ddos protection in single server app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

For a single server app I want protection against DDOS and encryption in transport.
From what I understand aws ALB does the ssl mitigation on the load balancer so I can connect to the target only on http. so if I want encryption in transit I cannot use ALB.

Is there a way to integrate waf/shield with ssl pass through or some other way to get encryption in transport with waf/shield integrated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AWS provides the option to create an HTTPS listner for your ALB, more details can be found in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html

> Add an HTTPS listener You configure a listener with a protocol and a
> port for connections from clients to the load balancer, and a target
> group for the default listener rule. For more information, see
> Listener configuration.
>
> Prerequisites
>
> To add a forward action to the default listener rule, you must specify
> an available target group. For more information, see Create a target
> group.
>
> To create an HTTPS listener, you must specify a certificate and a
> security policy. The load balancer uses the certificate to terminate
> the connection and decrypt requests from clients before routing them
> to targets. The load balancer uses the security policy when
> negotiating SSL connections with the clients.
>
> To add an HTTPS listener using the console
>
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Load Balancers.
>
> Select a load balancer, and choose Listeners, Add listener.
>
> For Protocol : port, choose HTTPS and keep the default port or enter a
> different port.
>
> (Optional) To authenticate users, for Default actions, choose Add
> action, Authenticate and provide the requested information. To save
> the action, choose the checkmark icon. For more information, see
> Authenticate users using an Application Load Balancer.
>
> For Default actions, do one of the following:
>
> Choose Add action, Forward to and choose a target group.
>
> Choose Add action, Redirect to and provide the URL for the redirect.
> For more information, see Redirect actions.
>
> Choose Add action, Return fixed response and provide a response code
> and optional response body. For more information, see Fixed-response
> actions.
>
> To save the action, choose the checkmark icon.
>
> For Security policy, we recommend that you keep the default security
> policy.
>
> For Default SSL certificate, do one of the following:
>
> If you created or imported a certificate using AWS Certificate
> Manager, choose From ACM and choose the certificate.
>
> If you uploaded a certificate using IAM, choose From IAM and choose
> the certificate.
>
> Choose Save.
>
> (Optional) To define additional listener rules that forward requests
> based on a path pattern or a hostname, see Add a rule.
>
> (Optional) To add a certificate list for use with the SNI protocol,
> see Add certificates to the certificate list.
>
> To add an HTTPS listener using the AWS CLI
>
> Use the create-listener command to create the listener and default
> rule, and the create-rule command to define additional listener rules.